# python fix TypeError: must be str, not int

Tags: python

hello every one I have problem of when I am trying to multiply the food price  by quantity of food

```
txtReceipt.insert(
    END,
    str(No) + "  " + str(my_text) + '\t\t' +\
    str(my_quantity) + '\t\t' + int(my_quantity) * int(price) + "\n"
)
```

I have this problem

```
TypeError: must be str, not int
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert your int object to string before concatenating. `str(int(my_quantity)*int(price))`

**Ex:**

```
txtReceipt.insert(END,str(No)+"  "+ str(my_text)+'\t\t'+str(my_quantity)+'\t\t'+str(int(my_quantity)*int(price))+"\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add a string and an integer, this is why the following segment of code raises an exception.

```
# Trying to add a string and an int raises a TypeError
'\t\t' + int(my_quantity) * int(price)
```

One solution is to cast your `int` to a `str` like so.

```
# This will now work
'\t\t' + str(int(my_quantity) * int(price))
```

Although, there exist cleaner syntax for string generation that implicitly cast objects to `str` for you.

#### Using `str.format`

```
'{}  {}\t\t{}\t\t{}\n'.format(
    No, my_text, my_quantity, int(my_quantity) * int(price)
)
```

#### Using literal string interpolation

The best approach, if you are using Python 3.6+, is to use f-strings.

```
f'{No}  {my_text}\t\t{my_quantity}\t\t{int(my_quantity) * int(price)}\n'
```